# Youtube going white on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, freeze, youtube

Whenever I use ubuntu and minimize the youtube videos from full-screen mode, the screen goes white. This never happened or never happens in windows. Why does it happen in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable hardware acceleration for Adobe Flash Player

   1. Right-click on the on the video you’re having issues with.
   2. Click **Settings**.
   3. If you see the option **Enable hardware acceleration**, uncheck it. If you don’t see it, the option is not available for you.
   4. Click **Close**.
   5. Refresh the page and check whether the video is working.
2. Update your graphics card driver if your computer has a discrete GPU

   1. Search in the Dash for *Additional Drivers*.
   2. Click the **Additional Drivers** icon to open Additional Drivers.
   3. From the list of drivers, select the graphics card driver that has *[Recommended]* after it by clicking it. The recommended graphics card driver for Ubuntu 12.04 will usually be up to date not far behind the latest version if your computer is not too old. If the driver is already installed, there will be a green dot to the left of it.
   4. Click the **Apply Changes** button in the lower right corner to install the recommended graphics card driver.
   5. Reboot to enable the graphics card driver.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I successfully completed disabling hardware acceleration. But, I could not update graphics card driver because when I opened additional drivers, I saw "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system". So how do I accomplish this task?

Comment: In the terminal run the command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to identify your graphic card name and chipset. If there is no [Recommended] graphics card driver in **Additional Drivers** that could mean that either your computer does not have a separate GPU so it is using the integrated CPU graphics, or that Ubuntu has already selected to use the graphics driver that comes with the Ubuntu installation media for best performance.